# Windows 7 not booting in for no reason

Tags: windows-7

I've been online last night and went to sleep, next day I wake up and try to boot my PC, it doesn't boot in. It just starts Windows and shows black screen with a cursor on it.

What I've tried:

1. Rebooting in Safe Mode / Normal
2. Automatic repair by Windows itself
3. Last good known configuration
4. Restore

Nothing worked. I've noticed that latest saved restore points are by Windows Update, so I think the problem might be caused from a Windows update? Any help is appreciated..

Comment: You can certainly try to restore before an update and see what happens. It wouldn't be the first time that an updated is released and makes certain systems stop working.

Answer (score -1):

Hit `Ctrl+Alt+Delete`. It will open the windows task manager. Point to new task, and type in `explorer.exe`. Hit `Run`.

It will open windows explorer. Then you can add explorer to startup...